# Javascript working in JSFiddle but not on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of jQuery that triggers a console log/mixpanel tracking event when the user scrolls below the gray area, one for hitting the bottom of the page and another for when the user scrolls back to the top of the page. I can trigger the console log in JSFiddle, but its not happening in the actual page, outside of jsfiddle.

```
$(function () {
var $win = $(window);

$win.scroll(function () {
    if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
        console.log("USER SCROLLED TO TOP");
        mixpanel.track(
            "User Scrolled To Top", {
            "url": window.location.href
        });
    } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() >= $('#top').height() - 0 && $win.height() + $win.scrollTop() <= $('#top').height() + 0) {
        console.log("VIEWED BELOW THE FOLD");
        mixpanel.track(
            "User Scrolled Below the fold", {
            "url": window.location.href
        });
    } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
        console.log("USER SCROLLED TO BOTTOM");
        mixpanel.track(
            "User Scrolled To Bottom", {
            "url": window.location.href
        });
    }
});
});
```

Open the console in dev tools to view the events: `USER SCROLLED TO TOP`, `VIEWED BELOW THE FOLD` and `USER SCROLLED TO BOTTOM`. Full code is in the fiddle here, while the scroll function is from line 1-26:
[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/mattography/xsLx9ojs/10/)

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console outside of jsfiddle?

Comment: No errors in the console. I do notice that the code within the `if` and `else if` statements is not being triggered either, to show/hide divs based on the `navigator.userAgent`, but it does work in the live page.

Comment: Are you sure you have a scroller in the window and you didnt put your content inside a scrollable div?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger, to see which parts actually get called?

Comment: @Kinnza - The code is working just fine in another page here (reporting in the console and triggering mixpanel tracking events): http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/sh2kpcux/1/ (on the live version as well), so its an isolated issue to the above code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it was actually a css issue, with an `overflow-x: hidden;` being used in the body. Removing that allowed the scroll function to trigger.